# Updating placeholder during runtime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, placeholder

here is the problem I am having with placeholder:

I have a repeater and within that repeater, I have an item template. Now this template is formatted with a couple of tables, but for this question I have removed them to make things easier to read:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">

   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phAnswers" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>               
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Then, on the event OnItemDataBound, I create a new placeholder, bind it to the existing on (phAnswers), however the placeholder is not updated with the radiobuttons/textboxs that are created:

```
    Dim rdList As New RadioButtonList
    Dim newRadio As New RadioButton

 If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
        (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then

        Dim tempPH As PlaceHolder

        tempPH = e.Item.FindControl("phAnswers")

        For x As Integer = 0 To (t_MC.Count - 1)

                newRadio = New RadioButton

                newRadio.ID = "Answer" + x.ToString
                newRadio.Text = t_MC(x).Value
                rdList.Controls.Add(newRadio)

            Next

   tempPH.Controls.Add(rdList)
```

Any ideas why phAnswers is not updated with the new tempPH placeholder?
Cheers

Comment: Update: I tried adding just the radio buttons instead of adding the radio buttons to a radiobuttonlist and they show up fine. hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnItemDataBound may be too late to add controls. Try it in OnItemCreated and see if that helps. It's a quick test - just change your repeater event declaration like this:

```
OnItemCreated="R1_ItemDataBound"
```

If this idea doesn't help, you can easily switch it back.

Edit - I just noticed something. To populate a RadioButtonList, you should use ListItems, like this:

```
ListItem item - new ListItem("your text", "your value");
rdList.Items.Add(item);
```

This is probably why your RadioButtonList did not appear, but lone radio buttons worked.

Comment: No luck with this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yeah...figures it was something silly like that. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Panel` instead of a `PlaceHolder`

Comment: Actually, I have tried using a Panel and I get the same results